# Pandas DataFrame output as ASCII ^A or Unicode SOH delimited file

Tags: python, pandas

Finished my processing of a DataFrame and now I want to export it. Normally I export it as a plain CSV and there isn't a problem. Today I am asked to export the file with a ASCII **^A** or the equivalent Unicode **SOH** delimiter. I will be frank this is the first time I have ever had to deal with ASCII/Unicode delimiters. Can you guys offer me some guidance/help as to how to go about this in pandas/python? I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you can convert any number to a character using `chr()`.  For your example I think you want `chr(1)` which is ASCII SOH.  You can then pass this as the separator:

```
df.to_csv('foo.txt', sep=chr(1))
```

Once you see what `chr(1)` produces (`\x01`), you may realize you can also write it this way:

```
df.to_csv('foo.txt', sep='\1')
```

The ASCII table, of course, is here: http://www.asciitable.com/

^A is ASCII SOH according to this: http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ctrl.htm - there is no Python escape code for it though.  `curses.ascii.SOH` is close, but it's actually just the constant `1` so pretty useless - you'd be better off just writing `SOH = '\1'` in your program.